# Probability Density Functions and Finding the Value of c

Tags: probability, integration, density-function

I have the following question:

Consider the following probability Density function:

$$f_n(x) = \begin{cases}c\cdot(x^n-x^{2n}) & : 0\leq x\leq 1 \\[1ex] 0 & : \textsf{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

And I am tasked to determine the value of $c$ in terms of $n$.   Would this mean I have to integrate this function from $0$ to $1$ with respect to $n$ and treat $x$ as a constant?   I am a little confused as to the wording of the question and would greatly appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And I am tasked to determine the value of $c$ in terms of $n$. Would this mean I have to integrate this function from $0$ to $1$ with respect to $n$ and treat $x$ as a constant? I am a little confused as to the wording of the question and would greatly appreciate any guidance.

Not quite.   Integrate $f_n(x)$ from $0$ to $1$ with respect to $\color{blue}x$, holding $n$ as constant, equat it to $1$ (since it is total probability), then solve for $c$.

$$\begin{align}1= & ~ \int_0^1 c(x^n-x^{2n})\operatorname d x \\[2ex] \vdots \\[2ex]\therefore c= & ~ \ldots \end{align}$$

Thus $c$ will be evaluated as some expression in terms of $n$.

Comment: Ah perfect thank you. I suppose "in terms of n" just means that the final function you get will be a function of n, correct? That is c = fn

Comment: @JmanxC That $c$ is to be expressed as *some* function of $n$, yes.